VSCode: Running python with sudo fixes missing module but it won't run without it? (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests')
Note: this problem seems to be a VSCode specific issue as I can run it outside of VSCode and it seems to work.  I want to get it working inside VSCode so I can debug it.
I have a virtualenv that I setup to isolate packages installed from the main system (for setup/testing purposes).  I'm having issues where I'm trying to install packages but it doesn't seem to want to find my module.
The code can be reproduced on my end with a single line of code (because the problem is that stupid):
import requests

I'm getting the following error when running "python3 test.py" (using python 3.10, to be clear):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Oddly enough, when I type "sudo python3 test.py", it runs fine.  This, to me, says whatever packages I'm installing are being installed into the wrong location or something to that effect.  That said, I can see the package just fine.
I have tried the following:
pip3 install requests
apt-get install python3-requests

I have also tried both of those using sudo, to see if that makes a difference (it doesn't).
I tried pip3 list and got the following:
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
certifi            2024.2.2
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
idna               3.7
pip                23.0.1
python-dateutil    2.9.0.post0
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         66.1.1
six                1.16.0
urllib3            2.2.1
wheel              0.38.4

I can see requests is installed, sudo can see requests installed, running it with just python3 (no sudo) can't seem to figure it out (at least not in VSCode).  Any ideas what might be going on?
Thanks!
EDIT:  I did find this:
When I try python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)", I get this:
['', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/jbrookley/sparrow/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

However, when I try sudo python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)", I get this:
['', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.11/dist-packages']

It looks like it's searching in different locations but it's also interesting that it's seeing 3.11 rather than 3.10 (my interpreter is set to 3.10).  Not sure if that tells me that VSCode isn't actually running from my virtualenv?

VSCode has its own installation of Python, separate from the system one.  You can override that, however.

It's odd that the output from the first print(sys.path) does not include the system default dist-packages folder, only your own personal site-packages folder.

Have you tried setting the python interpreter in USER settings.json and pointing it to python3.10?
